# create new dataframe based on frequency of dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have following dataset

```
Sector Sex
 A     Male
 C     Female
 B     Female
 B     Male
 A     Female
 A     Male
 C     Male
 C     Female
 B     Male
 B     Female
```

Code to reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A', Male],
    ['C', Female],
    ['B', Female],
    ['B', Male],
    ['A', Female],
    ['A', Male],
    ['C', Male],
    ['C', Female],
    ['B', Male],
    ['B', Female]
], 
    columns=['Sector', 'Sex'])
```

from the dataframe we can see Sector A has 2 Male and 1 Female, B has has 2 Male and 2 Female and C has 1 Male and 2 Female.
What I want is make Dataframe which has Sector, Male, Female, Total Column and contains the frequency of those column like below

```
Sector Male Female Total
A      2     1      3
B      2     2      4
C      1     2      3

I can crosstab but I want a different dataframe with the column name I mentioned
```

Comment: Use `df = pd.crosstab(df.Sector, df.Sex, margins=True, margins_name='Total').iloc[:-1]`